# Can I create an 2D texture array with different sizes for each textures?

Tags: opengl

I'm making a 2D game engine, and I need a way to batch all textures into one so I only make one `glBindTexture` call throughout a scene. I am trying to use 2D texture arrays, but they only support textures of the same size.

Do I have to conform to this, or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What user1118321 says is true -- all the textures need to be the same size.

But that doesn't mean you need to USE all the space.  For a small set of standalone textures, it's not a big deal to waste some space.

You can simply store the U/V coordinates of where a smaller texture ends and use that.  When creating the array, just set a max size and make sure everything is <= that.

Here's some code from my project that I use to do this -- it uses some data structures not presented here, so you'll have to modify it a bit, but the idea should help.  This works in 3.3 + a common extension or two (I forget which ones) or 4.3 (4.4?) without any (I think).

```
// this takes a vector containing the raw image data from the files (I use lodepng) as well as some sizing data also returned from lodepng
// max width/height are the actual size of the textures to be created
GLuint Graphics::make_texture_array(std::vector<ArrayTextureData> & 
textures, size_t max_width, size_t max_height, bool repeatable) {
    GLuint texture_name;
glGenTextures(1, &texture_name);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, texture_name);
std::vector<u_int32_t> clear_data(max_width * max_height, 0);

//  printf("Creating texture array with %d textures and  max texture width %d and max texture height %d\n", (int)textures.size(), max_width, max_height);
    glTexStorage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 3, GL_RGBA8, max_width, max_height, textures.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < textures.size(); i++) {
        auto & texture = textures[i];
//      printf("Loading texture into array at position %d actual texture w: %d actual texture h: %d with %d bytes\n", i, texture.width, texture.height, (int)texture.data.size());
        assert(texture.width <= max_width);
        assert(texture.height <= max_height);
        // set the whole texture to transparent (so min/mag filters don't find bad data off the edge of the actual image data)
        glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, 0, 0, i, max_width, max_height, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &clear_data[0]);
        glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, 0, 0, i, texture.width, texture.height, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &texture.data[0]);
        CHECK_GL_ERROR;
        texture.min_u = 0;
        texture.min_v = 0;
        texture.layer = i;
        texture.max_u = texture.width / static_cast<float>(max_width);
        texture.max_v = texture.height / static_cast<float>(max_height);
        texture.texture_id = texture_name;
    }
    if (repeatable) {
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    } else {
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    }

    // makes enlarged textures run faster but look awful
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY);
    CHECK_GL_ERROR;

    //Unbind texture
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, NULL);


    return texture_name;
}
```

Comment: Note that this breaks wrapping or clamping texture filters and may give you surprising samples around the virtual edges of your texture.

Comment: My textures tend to have transparent borders, so I guess it's just not an issue for me, but good callout.

Comment: I added some code that I use to do this.   It's probably not perfect and you'll have to adapt it to your own data structures, but I think it's relatively clear what it does

Comment: @xaxxon Thank you so much. Would it be a good idea for me to use more (about 3 or 4) array textures of different max sizes to reduce unfilled data? They would be sized icon, small, medium, large, etc.

Comment: @fridgemagnet I mean, really it depends how much stuff you're loading.. but when even crappy integrated stuff has at least 512MB, it takes a lot of empty space before it starts to matter.   Also, there's no reason you couldn't programatically load up a few really small ones onto a single texture and have the min_u/min_v not be 0 for them - a an array of texture atlases.

Comment: My comp has 512 MB VRAM :(

Comment: Then you'll be fine!   I'm on a machine with Intel 3000 graphics right now and using the code above to load 50-60 things at about.. probably 50% efficiency

Comment: I updated the code to more properly set min/mag filters as well as some code to get rid of the issue (or at least minimize) @LarsViklund brought up.  Now, it initializes the entire texture to a transparent background before loading up the actual texture data.   This gets rid of the dark border around the outside when linear filters are used.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "so I only make one glBindTexture call throughout a scene." What advantage does that get you?

2D texture arrays [require the textures to be the same size](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Array_Texture). I don't know of any way around that.

One other option you have is to use a texture atlas. You can make a single texture that contains all of your assets and simply pass the appropriate texture coordinates for each texture use. I found [this tutorial](http://androidblog.reindustries.com/a-real-opengl-es-2-0-2d-tutorial-part-7-texture-atlas/). It uses OpenGL ES 2, but it should give you the general idea.

Comment: Using many glBindTextures per frame will screw with my performance, so I need to bind one big texture array for each scene of the game.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to restrict yourself to drivers which expose [Bindless Textures](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Bindless_Texture) you can make all the textures you want resident, put their handles in an uniform or structured buffer as `sampler2D` values and use those transparently in your shader.

If not, you could have a series of texture arrays, one for each size and in your shader code branch to select the correct array.